# File name is coming in SQL query output from unix

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, ksh

I have written a simple `sh` file to retrieve data from Oracle SQL but getting error. Following is my code:

```
.  $HOME/.profile

function assignVariables
{

    ID="finapp"
    PASS="finapp"
    MAIL_BODY_PATH="/rbluat/BACKEND/Finacle/FC10.2.9/app/CDCI_LOGS/"

}

echo $ID
echo $PASS
function getDatatrans
{

            TRANID=`sqlplus -s $ID/$PASS@rbluat <<EOF
            SELECT DISTINCT TRAN_ID,DTH_INIT_SOL_ID,TRAN_DATE,DEL_FLG FROM TBAADM.DTD WHERE PSTD_FLG='N' AND ENTRY_USER_ID='FIVUSR' and del_flg='N' and tran_date=(select db_stat_date from tbaadm.gct)AND REF_NUM IN (SELECT PYMT_REF_NUM FROM TBAADM.PORD WHERE STATUS IN ('A','H'));
exit;
EOF`
}

assignVariables

getDatatrans
echo $TRANID
```

I am getting output as :

```
 [YOU HAVE NEW MAIL]


 SELECT DISTINCT TRAN_ID,DTH_INIT_SOL_ID,TRAN_DATE,DEL_FLG FROM TBAADM.DTD WHERE PSTD_FLG='N' AND ENTRY_USER_ID='FIVUSR' and del_flg='N' and tran_date=(select db_stat_date from tbaadm.gct)AND REF_NUM IN (SELECT PYMT_REF_NUM FROM TBAADM.PORD WHERE STATUS IN ('A','H')) few.sh test.sh ERROR at line 1: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

`

Here `few.sh` and `test.sh` are the file names present in the current working directory. `few.sh` is the file where I have written this code. I have no idea how these names are coming. I am working in KSH. I tried googling about it but found no clue.

Comment: You have a `MAIL_BODY_PATH`, do you send the mail or is the mail from cron? And please check in sqlplus: table TBAADM.PORD, should that be PRODm do you need a space before AND in `tbaadm.gct)AND` ?

Comment: @WalterA, I am planning to send the mail from `few.sh` only which will be run by cron. I will check the sql command though.

Comment: Did you check the sql?

Comment: @WalterA, I checked later and came to know db was down while I was testing. So after it was brought up, I tested again and the same code worked.

Answer (score 0):

The output of sqlplus in evaluated in the command

```
echo $TRANID
```

When TRANID has a `*` in it, ksh will show the files it can find.
You should use quotes to avoid evaluation:

```
echo "$TRANID"
```

When you are editing you code, you might as well add {} (not needed here, good habit):

```
echo "${TRANID}"
```

Likewise:

```
echo "${ID}"
echo "${PASS}"
...
-s "${ID}/${PASS}@rbluat"
```